# States: Extension

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

**Definition**

Define positivity in terms of:
$$\omega\geq0:\iff\omega(X^*X)\geq0$$
*(This way it serves best for the GNS-construction.)*

**Problem**

Given a C*-algebra $1\notin\mathcal{A}$ and adjoin a unit $\mathcal{A}\oplus\mathbb{C}$.

Consider a linear functional $\omega:\mathcal{A}\to\mathbb{C}$.

Then it has a canonical extenion:
$$\omega_E(X+x1):=\omega(X)+x\|\omega\|$$

Then does it remain bounded and positive:
$$\omega\geq0\implies\omega_E\geq0$$
$$\|\omega\|<\infty\implies\|\omega_E\|<\infty$$
Especially, does it maintain norm: $\|\omega_E\|=\|\omega\|$

*(Revisiting Hahn-Banach, this extension may be even discontinuous!)*

The problem is that I don't get ahead at:
$$X+x1\geq0:\quad\omega_E(X+x1)=\omega(Y^2)+2y\omega(Y)+y^2=\ldots$$
$$\|X+x1\|<1:\quad|\omega_E(X+x1)|\leq|\omega(X)|+|x|=\ldots$$
Exploiting the representation: $X+x1=(Y+y1)(Y+y1):\quad Y=Y^*,y=\overline{y}$

**Reference**

I found a treatment of this in: Bratelli & Robinson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I finally figured it out; both separately...*

Suppose it holds: $\omega(A^*A)\geq0$

Positivity can be proven by Kadison's inequality:
$$\omega_E\left((A+a1)^*(A+a1)\right)=\omega(A^*A)+a\omega(A^*)+\overline{a}\omega(A)+|a|^2\|\omega\|\\\geq\omega(A^*A)-2|a|\omega(A^*A)^{\frac12}\|\omega\|^{\frac12}+|a|^2\|\omega\|=\left(\omega(A^*A)^{\frac12}-|a|\|\omega\|^{\frac12}\right)^2\geq0$$

Suppose it holds: $\lim\omega(E)=\|\omega\|$

Boundedness can be proven by an approximate identity:
$$|\omega_E(A+a1)|=|\omega(A)+a\|\omega\||=\lim|\omega(AE)+a\omega(E)|\\\leq\limsup\|\omega\|\cdot\|aE+AE\|\leq\|\omega\|\cdot\|a1+A\|\cdot1$$
*(Beware the limessuperior as the approximate identity alone diverges!)*